# How to redirect to another component from current component and also pass the props to redirect component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a note app. So basically the app adds, edit and delete notes.

For editing the note. I have to click the edit button of the note. 
It should trigger a function which redirects to UpdateNote component 
and also the Note ID should be passed to the Update component.

My Posts Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Post from "../../components/Post/Post";

class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    error: false
  };

  fetchNotes = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/notes")
      .then(response => {
        //console.log(response.data);
        const posts = response.data;
        this.setState({ posts: posts });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error: true });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchNotes();
  }

  render() {
    let posts = <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Something went wrong!</p>;

    if (this.state.posts.length === 0) {
      posts = <p>Oops no post to show...</p>;
    } else if (!this.state.error) {
      posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
        //console.log(post._id);
        return (
          <Post
            key={post._id}
            title={post.title}
            text={post.text}
            id={post._id}
            fetchNotes={this.fetchNotes}
            edit={} // <-- HERE
          />
        );
      });
    }

    return <div>{posts}</div>;
  }
}

export default Posts;
```

what should i pass in edit={} . so that it is redirected to update component and also the post_.id is passed to updatecomponent. Can any one help me.

Any kind of code suggestion would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to navigate to a new route where your UpdateNote component is rendered, and that route should have the post._id as a url parameter. That way, your UpdateNote component will be able to get the post id from its route props.

So, if you're using React Router DOM, the edit prop on the post component will be the following function:

```
() => history.push(`${yourUpdateNoteRoute}${post._id}`)
```